# Replace using statement with equal try/finally block

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, memorystream

How to replace this statement with try/finally block?

```
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()){}
```

Is this the correct approach?

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
try
{
   //code
}
finally
{
   ms.Dispose();                
}
```

Comment: why would you want to do that?. Why not use the using block inside the try catch??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's rather like this:

```
MemoryStream ms = null;
try
{
   ms = new MemoryStream();

   //code
}
finally
{
   if (ms != null) ms.Dispose();                
}
```

The reason is that the mere instantiation may create disposable resources.